# Наследование JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Начал изучать Java и не могу понять работу наследования.

Имеется класс, наследуемый от Pane.

```
public class Tone extends Pane{

   int x = 100;
   int y = 100;
   Background skin = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.rgb(255, 255, 0), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));

   Tone() {
       this.setPrefSize(this.x, this.y);
       this.setBackground(this.skin);
       this.setOnMouseEntered(e ->{
           show();
       });
       this.setOnMouseExited(e -> {
           show();
       });
   }

   void show() {
       if(this.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
           Text stat = new Text(this.x + " " + this.y);
           this.getChildren().add(stat);
       } 
       else {
           this.getChildren().clear();
       }
   }
}
```

От данного класса наследуется другой класс, в котором изменены значения переменных.

```
public class Ttwo extends Tone {

   int x = 300;
   Background skin = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));

}
```

При создании объекта Ttwo не меняет свой размер, отображение значения, а так же цвет фона.

Подскажите, в чем заключается ошибка?

Comment: Вы не задали модификатор доступа для полей, поэтому у подкласса и суперкласса свои экземпляры полей `x` и `skin`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Не совсем понял вас. Какой именно модификатор мне нужно в данном случае использовать? Каким именно будет решение?

Comment: Создание объекта второго класса влечёт за собой вызов конструктора родительского класса, который использует значения полей своего класса для инициализации

Comment: @Serodv хорошо, это я понял. Каким образом мне сделать так, чтобы использовались значения конкретно данного класса?

Comment: Создайте параметризированній конструктор, тогда и наследование не особо то и нужно будет

Comment: @Serodv в данном случае указана только проблема,а не весь функционал. Тут требуется именно наследование.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В классе `Ttwo` нет ни одного места, которое бы работало с переменными `x` и `skin`, более того называть переменные дочернего класса именами родительского класса является стилистической ошибкой.
Вызывая метод show() у экземпляра `Ttwo` выполняется блок кода написанный в `Tone`и используются переменные, находящиеся в этом же файле. 
То, что вам нужно - это передать в конструкторе `Ttwo` значения переменных в родительский класс.